# In the game "Skate"...what in the world is Jason Lee (The Coach) saying?

Tags: skate

I was watching the demo to Skate the other day, and there's a voice actor (clearly Jason Lee, of My Name is Earl Fame) who kept repeating something like "ki ki kia" from time to time.

Clearly this is some kind of skating lingo. Does anyone know what he's saying, and what it means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jason Lee was a (quite legendary) professional skateboarder long before he was ever in My Name is Earl. He's saying 'git git yeah', and it doesn't mean anything at all.. In fact, it's pretty annoying.

Comment: Is that a Jason Lee specific catch-phrase, or is it general skating slang?

Comment: it's like, "get over here and skate." also like "double time" or "let's get going"

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens it is not general skating slang.